# In a content creation form, can one field acquire its default from another?

Tags: entities

I have a content type with the following fields:

- Name (text)
- Image1 (image)
- Field set (field_collection)
  - Image2 (image)
  - Description (text)

I would like the value of image1 to become the **default** value of image2.
Another option is to hide Image2 if Image1 has a value.

The Field Collection is set to have unlimited instances.

I've examined conditional fields which looks like its logic won't cross the field collection boundary.

Is there a way to do this that I've missed?

Comment: Are you in need of a ready made solution, or form api one? My most recent question was about form api one, but it would require pretty some coding from you.

Comment: @Mołot, unfortunately, I could manage only a little bit of coding.  I would prefer a module with capabilities that lend themselves to the solution.

Comment: Try to play with [conditional fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. I'm afraid if that's not enough, you'll have to hire a contractor.